# Browser crashes when taking picture with camera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, html5-canvas

I've got a simple page that allows you to take a picture with your phone and then upload it to the server.

To achieve that, I'm using HTML5's input as file, so when I click (or tap on) Choose File two options are displayed:

1. Use the phone's camera (I'm using an iPhone with iOS8)
2. Select a picture from the library.

If I select the picture from the library everything works just fine, as for now I'm only displaying it on screen, but if I use the camera, after taking the picture the browser crashes. I haven't been able to debug because it never hits my breakpoints since the debugging session crashes as well.

Here's the code. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<!--Seg:openPage-->
<script>
function resizeImg(img, canvas, ctx){

    var MAX_WIDTH = 500;
    var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;

    alert(width + " " + height);

    if (width > height) {
        if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
            width = MAX_WIDTH;
        }
    } else {
        if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
        }
    }

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    //var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(img, 0.5);
    //img.src = dataURL; 

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
}


function drawOnCanvas(file) {

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {

        var dataURL = e.target.result;
        var c = document.querySelector('canvas');
        var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();

        img.src = dataURL;
        //****img.onload = function() {
        //c.width = 200; //img.width;
        //c.height = 200; //img.height;
        if (img.complete) {
            resizeImg(img, c, ctx);
            //ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        } else {
            img.onload = function () {
                resizeImg(img, c, ctx);
                //ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            };
        }
        //ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        //****};
        //****img.src = dataURL;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
    }


function upload(file){

    var encodedB64 = window.btoa(file);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend=function(){
        if(file){
            //reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            console.log(reader);
            //alert(reader.result);
            $('.output').val(reader.result);
        }

        submit_form('f','GO');
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');

    input.onchange = function () {
      var file = input.files[0];

      //upload(file);
      drawOnCanvas(file);   
      //displayAsImage(file); 
    };

});
</script>

<style>
/**
#canvas-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#canvas-container #myCanvas{
    width: 100%;
}**/
</style>
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 10px;">
<div id="page_content">
<form name="f" method="POST" action="@&PGM " class="sigPad">
    <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">

    <!--Add file input-->
    <p>Choose a picture from your device or capture one with your camera now:</p>
    <input type="file" id="picManager" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

    <!--Add canvas-->
    <p>Photo:</p>
    <div id="canvas-container">
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">View</button>



</form>
</div>
</div>
<!--End:openPage-->
```

Comment: "website crashes"? If someone trying to upload a picture causes your server to crash, you've got much bigger problems than the upload not working properly... Perhaps you mean the web BROWSER or web VIEW in your phone crashes?

Comment: My mistake, BROWSER crashes, I'll correct it

Comment: When **the whole browser crashes** and not just your Javascript program, the bug is in the browser, not (just) in your code. You should report it to the developers of your browser. When you want a workaround until it is fixed, please post **which web browser** you are using.

Comment: Hey Philipp, I'm using Safari for iOS

Comment: johansebasb did you find a solution or workaround for this?

Comment: @kumar no, sorry, we decided to use the picture that was taken at the moment without accessing the photo library